# MySQL Backup Best practice

Tags: mysql, backup

I have a Mysql server which is running on linux box (Azure cloud). It has huge datas and many schemas, i want to take backup of each database separately. I had a shell scripts which basically runs mysqldump to take backup of each database and zip it. But the problem is it takes too much of time and also it locks the running system, I basically don't want to stop my system for backing up as i take backup every two days. Can you please suggest the best way to achieve my backup very fast and without interrupting the running system. By the way my Mysql server is not a Enterprise edition.

Comment: I suggest to move this discussion to either ServerFault or Superuser. Stackoverflow is for coding issues.

Comment: Cross-post: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/160375/mysql-backup-best-practice